# Using javascript to alter content of a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you alter the content of a `<div>` using javascript when the `<div>` has no `id` or `class`.

I know that using something like `document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'Your content';` Could have been used if the `<div>` had an id. But in my case the content I want to alter is like this

```
<div unselectable="on" style="position: absolute; padding: 2px; top: 0px; left: 1px; background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0); color: white;">BOO</div>
```

I am partial to using `document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = "BOO";` to find it but how do I then proceed to modify its content? Also is this a good way to doing things?

Comment: Is that the only div in your document?

Comment: No there are other div too but that is the only one with that content `Boo`

Comment: You need to have valid identifier to your element to manipulate it using JS.. by using getElementsByTagName, you need to know the index of element..

Comment: @panther it is inside this one `<div unselectable="on" class="calendar_white_corner_inner"></div>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> No there are other div too but that is the only one with that content Boo

If that case, you can find by `:contains`

```
$("div:contains('BOO')").html('hello');
```

Comment: OP didnt say he is using jQuery.

Comment: @Warlock, they did. They tagged it jQuery :)

Comment: @TheWarlock He did. See tagged.

Comment: I have jquery 1.9 loaded in the page @The Warlock

Comment: @RickRoy - tagging a question does not necessarily say you have that loaded in your project.

Comment: @TheWarlock : Or maybe he saying that, either native javascript or jquery answers are acceptable then.